# phpmyadmin and speed of my mac

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

Really new with the whole phpMyAdmin thing.

I was wondering, when I enable my computer for web sharing, then install phpMyAdmin, is this detrimental to my computer in anyway (mainly in speed)?  If so, I would opt for just using another (older) computer.  But that would be a hassle.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hosting pages on your Mac will use some resources, however if you are not sending much content to very many users, it is unlikely that you will notice the performance hit.  Give it a try to find out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are potential security issues depending on your set up and a slight impact on speed since youll be running the webserver and mysql in the background but its nothing huge in terms of performance.

With that said theres no need to use phpmyadmin locally. Its kind of pointless since you can use a real mysql client like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/), [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/), or [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). I prefer Sequel Pro myself since its free and pretty lightweight.